# underline output in python from user?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm taking multi-line input from users and then I'm trying print its output but I want to underline some text under a condition if the user wants to underline a particular line.
**Condition: user want to underline text which is under `$text$` symbols.** 
*Example: Text under $TEXT$*

I'm using `pywhatkit` library in python to convert my text into handwriting.

[image]
I want that user wants underline the second line if he put $ I want to underline my this line $ so it underline my output

Here is my python code:

```py
from colorama import init
from termcolor import colored
import pywhatkit as kit
print("")
init()
print(colored('Support me on Instagram: @shiva5harma ', 'white', 'on_red'))
print("")

print("Enter/Paste your content. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z ( windows ) to save it.")
contents = []
while True:
    try:
        text = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    contents.append(text)

print("")

print("-- Lcation Example: C:/User/owner/Desktop/image_name.png  --")
print("")
path=str(input("Enter Location where to store image\n"))
try:
  print("")
  print("I'm working on it Please Wait.......\n")
#   kit.text_to_handwriting(text,path)
  text = "\n".join(contents)  # Make one big string of all individual input lines
  kit.text_to_handwriting(text,path)  # Use the new parameter
except:
   print("Error Occured")
finally:
   print("Your Image is ready !! Your will find your Image here\n",path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately not supported yet and this is quite difficult to achieve so I don't think we will be able to include this feature in future.
If you want to know how this text to handwriting works in order to try to implement the above mentioned feature please have a look at this repo https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/pywhatkit.herokuapp.com/blob/main/app.py

Comment: sure I'll try to do this !

Answer (score 2):

**You can try using escape characters in your string**

```py
# This will print Unicode Character ('combining low line' U+0332) as underlines 

#sentence = s
s = "$Hello I want to underline my text$"

if (s[0]=="$" and s[len(s)-1]=="$"):
    s = s[1:]#removes first $
    s = s[:-1]# removes last char $
    s = "\u0332".join(s)
print(s)
```

```
 H̲e̲l̲l̲o̲ ̲I̲ ̲w̲a̲n̲t̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲e̲ ̲m̲y̲ ̲t̲e̲x̲t
```

Unfortunately the documentation for pywhatkit  is somewhat limited in this regard (in my opinion), so there's no guarantee it will work / has support for it.

Comment: I guess "\u0332" is not working because your code is not working in my system.

Comment: Yes unfortunately it requires ANSI support and pywhatkit most likely is not compatible with it.

Comment: No rn I'm not using pywhatkit ! I'm using your code but it's doesn't work.

Comment: Some consoles cant display UTF-8 and  ANSI styled characters unless configured. You can try this code on a external site like [replit](https://replit.com/languages/python3)

Comment: so how can I run this in kali Linux any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to see the underline in console you probably need to enable UTF-8. [How can I enable UTF-8 support in the Linux console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303712/how-can-i-enable-utf-8-support-in-the-linux-console)

Comment: It's ookk! if it's not working but you gave me really helpful logic Thanks for it.

Comment: Please correct your facts, Pywhatkit doesn't have limited documentation, you can find all the details in my GitHub repo of Pywhatkit or on the official pypi page https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/PyWhatKit.

Comment: It was not a "fact", more like an opinion. In my eyes the documentation that is available is rather "limited" . Yes everything can be found in the code in itself but the documentation is lacking explaining the function themselves. I have edited the comment so it better represents my point.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I will try to include detailed documentation.